# How to copy data from one cell to another - depending on the cell next to it?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, vlookup

I'm trying to:
In cell C3, search Column J to find an identical match of B3, then copy the data from Lx.
In cell D3, Search Column J to find an identical match of B3, then copy the data from Mx.

There are 10285 rows of data.

[image: My current problem!]

I have tried several IF and VLOOKUP statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the group of columns, J:L, L is the fourth column, so use 4 in VLOOKUP:

Formula for C3:

```
=VLOOKUP($B3,$J:L,3,FALSE)
```

D3 is the same, but with 4 instead of 3 to get M.

If you want to get fancy and have the formula copy nicely across columns, you can use the COLUMN() function to help calculate the 3s and 4s:

Formula for C3:

```
=VLOOKUP($B3,$J:L,COLUMN(L3)-COLUMN($J3)+1,FALSE)
```

Then when you copy that from C3 to D3, the L becomes M and the column calculation produces 4 instead of 3.

Comment: L. Scott Johnson is right to recommend whole columns for the lookup range. In this formula, the lookup range `J:L` is all of columns J, K, and L. Whole columns is the easiest way to write a VLOOKUP formula. Another common problem with writing a VLOOKUP formula is understanding that the `3` in this formula means the third column of the lookup range (not an offset of 3 columns). Another common problem is understanding that `FALSE` means an exact match.